# How to match a regex and replace in middle of matched result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

How to match a regex and replace in middle of matched result

**Example of faulty address:**

> My street address 8 -24
>
> My street address 8 24 (I need add dash between and result should be **8-24**)
>
> My - street address  8 -24 (should not remove - from "My - street")

**My current code**

```
address_as_array.each do |row|
  aadress_white_space_removed << row.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').gsub(/\s\-/, '-').strip.mb_chars.downcase.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
/(\d)\s*[-\s]\s*(\d)/
```

and replace with `'\1-\2'`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cYCafR/1)

**Details**

- `(\d)` - Group 1 (later referenced to with the help of `\1` replacement backreference from the string replacement pattern): any digit
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[-\s]` - one hyphen or whitespace
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d)` - Group 2 (later referenced to with the help of `\2` replacement backreference): any digit.

In your code, you may use it as

```
aadress_white_space_removed << row.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').gsub(/(\d)\s*[-\s]\s*(\d)/, '\1-\2').strip.mb_chars.downcase.to_s
```